# If username is set and password is not, display me an error message

Tags: php, html

```
    <div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<?php
      if (isset($_POST['username']) && !isset($_POST['password']))  {
    echo "Please enter your password.";
}?>
```

I just want to display an error message IF username IS set and password field is not filled with any character after click on "submit", this is how I tried but now working for me.

Comment: when submitting the form `$_POST['password']` is set, but it is empty

Comment: I also tried with " if empty ($_POST['password']) but I got the same results

Comment: empty won't work either...empty works on false.  Use `@$_POST['password'] == ""`

Comment: Try that---   

if ((isset($_POST['username']) && (!isset($_POST['password']))))  {
    echo "Please enter your password.";
      }

Comment: @Forbs It's generally not a good idea to use the suppression operator on anything, it can cause a lot more issues down the road for you.

Comment: The required attribute on your inputs will make this difficult to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form you are missing an action. Inside the action attribute put the same URL that you did below. Also, you should check if the submit `POST` is set.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['password'] == "")  {
    echo "Please enter your password.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'] == ""))  {
    echo "Please enter your password.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Below your form enter the following:

```
if ((isset($_POST['username'])) == true && (isset($_POST['password'])) == false ){
   echo "please enter your password";
}
```

This means that if the username is set and the password is NOT set it will display the error message of: "please enter you password".
You can change this and use it as a template:

```
if ((isset($_POST['value'])) == true && (isset($_POST['value2'])) == false{
   echo "error message!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.